# External dll function with .h file gives no return value, but gives an error. (DLL and function does work perfect in VBA)

Tags: c++

External DLL function which returns an integer (no arguments) gives a compiler error:

> cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)()' in assignment

I expect an `int` return value (in VBA it does work, but in C++ it does not).

In `.h` file:

```
extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall WieOpenDev(void);
}
```

Code in `main.cpp`:

```
int (*fcnPtrGetDev)();
fcnPtrGetDev = WieOpenDev;
std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev << '\n';
```

Gives an error while compiling:

> cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)()' in assignment

I tried to use this DLL function in VBA. It does work perfectly, the return value is `6`, which is correct.

But C++ gives that error.

I also tried:

```cpp
int GetDev;
GetDev = WieOpenDev;
```

Which gives a different error while compiling:

> invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Calling convention mismatch, fix with `int (__stdcall * fcnPtrGetDev)();`  If you want to see 6 then write std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev() << etc.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work fine for `x64` targets, but for `Win32` targets the `__stdcall` actually makes a difference here. For both targets the following code should compile:

```
int (__stdcall* fcnPtrGetDev)();
fcnPtrGetDev = WieOpenDev;
std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev;
```

see [godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aextern+%22C%22+%7B%0A++__declspec(dllimport)int+++__stdcall+WieOpenDev(void)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+f()%0A%7B%0A++++int+(__stdcall*+fcnPtrGetDev)()%3B%0A++++fcnPtrGetDev+%3D+WieOpenDev%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+fcnPtrGetDev%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x86,options:%27%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+2/15%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Note: To actually call the function pointed to by the function pointer, you need to use

```
std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev();
```

instead of

```
std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev;
```

The latter results in the pointer value being printed instead of the result of calling the function.

Comment: `std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev;` needs to be `std::cout << fcnPtrGetDev();` instead.  The 1st just prints the address of the function, the 2nd actually calls the function